# iAd works on simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone, iad

I am updating an app with iAd.  The current version has iAd, and everything works great.  But the changes have been substantial enough that I want to test the ads again before I submit the update.

When I test iAd on the simulator, I get the test advertisement with no problem.  When I try to test it on the device, all I get are calls to didFailToReceiveAdWithError.  The descriptions of the error are either:

"The operation couldn't be completed.  Ad inventory unavailable."

or:

"The operation couldn't be completed.  Unknown error."

In light of this, how can I make sure the ads will work in the updated app?

Comment: hi there did you ever solve this problem? i have the same problem, test ads works properly on the simulator but not on the device, with the same error description **The operation couldn't be completed. Ad inventory unavailable.**

Comment: I don't remember.  But I'm guessing Vinnie's answer has a clue.

Comment: thanks for the reply, its seems the test ads works fine now both on the device and the simulator, and i noticed they have changed the test ads(not the old test black banner), perhaps their test ads wont work before because they made some changes.. BTW i followed the apple's iAd programming guide.

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with the "Unknown error" message for close to 9 hours.  For me, my iPod touch had reset itself to 1970.  I accidentally let the battery drain and the time & date got set back.  I never bothered to set it back because I don't use that often.  Once I set the date to the current date, that and other things began to work correctly (in-app purchases were also screwed up).

Comment: What's the question and what has been answered :O

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the ADBannerView delegate.

Comment: I have -- and I'm getting callbacks -- as described in my post.