# iAd banner is displayed on simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

I'm working on my iPhone application and I integrated iAd banners in all views of the app, sharing an unique banner object created on the app delegate.

I'm able to display the iAd test banner on the simulator and it works fine, but when I try to install the app on the iPhone 3GS iOS 5.1 from  Xcode, the iAd test banner simply is never displayed. All the times I've received the following error, on the banner delegate didFailToReceiveAdWithError:

Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn\u2019t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable" UserInfo=0x58dd80 {ADInternalErrorCode=3, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable}

Is this normal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iAd works on simulator but not on device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898902/iad-works-on-simulator-but-not-on-device)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with iPad. I am running iPad 2 with iOS 4.3, and get the "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable." error each time. I tried it in the simulator, and for every available iOS running on iPad, I received the error. I should note that it is an iPhone app running on the iPad - I don't know if that has any bearing on things. So my thought is that perhaps iAds don't run in iPhone apps that run on the iPad... wish I could give you a more concrete answer, and I will try to come back and post if I get one. Would also appreciate hearing what you find.

EDIT:
I just discovered this technical note with information regarding iPhone apps running in compatibility mode on the iPad:
"Phone apps running in compatibility mode on iPad will not display a test ad in development or live ads in deployed apps running in the compatibility environment. To ensure that your app is capable of displaying iAd banners for all your customers, make sure you’ve developed an app that supports all possible devices."
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2264/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that looks normal. It means that there just isn't enough ad inventory for your app. Perhaps inventory is just low or perhaps it is not available for your particular area.

If you want more ad inventory to be available to your app, I'd suggest you use an ad mediation system like [AdMob mediation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation).

Comment: Thanks @ThomasW, make sense, I'm from Mexico, I've integrated both in my app, I'm using iAd as default and AdMob as backup, is just a matter to play with delegates to hide and show the banners in the right moment. I was only concerned the inability show the test iAd on real device... and I just wanted to know if this was normal. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @IvanCastaneda If you use AdMob mediation (or a similar system) it supports switching between the two ad networks automatically. Also, you can add additional networks which may be more appropriate for your location, which can be especially appropriate if your app targets specific locales.

Answer (score 0):

"iPhone apps running in compatibility mode on iPad will not display a test ad in development or live ads in deployed apps running in the compatibility environment."

From Technote TN2264.